Azure Security Group members userprincipal name are returned as nulls when called using API
I am trying to call fetch all the members present in a security group using. I am using the same API call in graph API explorer and fabric notebook. Still the JSON returned are different. Graph explorer returns the user principal name of the user but the python call doesn't. I have given maximum scopes yet it is not resolved.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members/?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName

I have given all the maximum scopes member read all, directory read all, user basic read all, user read all, group member read all and group read all.

Any update on the issue?

To fetch the Microsoft Entra security group members using Fabric notebook, check the below:
Grant GroupMember.Read.All application type API permission to the Microsoft Entra ID application:

And make use of below python code:
import requests
import msal

client_id = 'CLientID'
client_secret = 'ClientSecret'
tenant_id = 'TenantID'
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    group_id = 'GroupID'

    url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        members = response.json()
        print("Group Members:", members)
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve group members: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.json())
else:
    print(f"Failed to acquire token: {result.get('error')}")
    print(result.get('error_description'))



Output:
Group Members: {'@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects(id,displayName,userPrincipalName)', 'value': [{'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.user', 'id': 'xxx', 'displayName': 'Testuser', 'userPrincipalName': 'Testuser@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.user', 'id': 'xxx', 'displayName': 'ruk', 'userPrincipalName': 'druk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.group', 'id': 'xxx', 'displayName': 'group1'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.group', 'id': 'xxx', 'displayName': 'rukgroup'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.user', 'id': 'xxx', 'displayName': 'demouser', 'userPrincipalName': 'demouser@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'}, {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.user', 'id': 'xxx', 'displayName': 'testmr', 'userPrincipalName': 'testmr@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'}]}

